# Eclipse compilation put lots of .class files in the package folders

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I must have done something very stupid which has caused the following situation. Basically after compilation of code which I had compiled successfully lots of times previously, all of the .class files have all of a sudden been put in the package folders, where the .java files are. Some of the .class files have even numbers in the names like.

```
ClassName.java
ClassName.class
ClassName$1.class
ClassName$2.class
ClassName$3.class
ClassName$4.class
```

It looks a mess in the Navigator and rebuilding or cleaning the project doesn't make these files go away.

The last code change I made, which has now been reverted was in the class static field:

```
static {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")) { CONTROL_PANEL_WIDTH = 225; }
    else { CONTROL_PANEL_WIDTH = 180; }

System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name")); // this is what I added; perhaps it was stupid
}
```

I must have done something silly. Can you help please?

Comment: Cleaning the project just removes the .class files from the package folders and then adds them back again.

Comment: So you are getting class files under `src/` instead of `bin/`? This is a project setup error, nothing to do with code. Did you change anything else outside the code?

Comment: This must be it. I don't think I've changed anything unless I did some involuntary keyboard shortcut or whatever,  but yes, I do not have the bin folder anymore. I will try to investigate the proejct setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have switched your default output folder of your classes, which can be fixed by right click your project -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> Tab `Source` -> `Default Output folder` (set it to `<ProjectName>/bin`)

You could also check the `.classpath` file in your workspace which have to look like this (the path of the output folder is stored relative):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: This was it! For some reason by bin folder gone AWOL. I have recreated it, set it as output folder and noticed that my new .class file have been put there on compilation. After that I have removed the .class files from my source folders and my project was unaffected by this. cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project, click properties

search for java build path,

click on source, here there is the config where the class must go

Don't check "allow output folders for source folder" and check that the path below is good

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project.  Select Build Path / Configure Build Path.  Select the Source tab.  Ensure that the Default output path is not your /src folder.

Somehow you or eclipse managed to lose the output folder for the compiler.

Comment: Yep, my bin folder has gone awol. I have recreated it and set as output folder. thanks for your help.